# YouTube Android APi v3 - GestureDetector

Tags: youtube-api, gesture, android-youtube-api

I've added a GestureDetector to the YouTubePlayerFragment in a dialog and it works fine - flings up, down, left and right can be detected. I also have a custom fullscreen handler where I hide widgets and make the player (still in the dialog) fullscreen and landscape. The GestorDetector behaves weirdly when fullscreen. It consistently takes 3, 4, or even 5 flings before the onTouch method of the player view is fire. Has anybody else seen this behaviour or have an idea on how to fix?

Comment: Have you found the solution for this.Please share if you find the solution..

Comment: No, I submitted it to the YouTube development team, they acknowledged but there's been no follow up

Comment: Please share the feedback once you received from them